# Istio-ingressgateway with https - Connection refused

Tags: istio

Following this [doc](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/) I got istio-ingressgateway running but using curl to test the URL I am facing this problem:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to httpbin.example.com port 31390: Connection refused
```

This is the Gateway:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: mygateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: httpbin-credential # must be the same as secret
    hosts:
    - httpbin.example.com
```

and the virtual service:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: httpbin
spec:
  hosts:
  - "httpbin.example.com"
  gateways:
  - mygateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /status
    - uri:
        prefix: /delay
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 8000
        host: httpbin
```

I am using istio 1.5.4.

This is the command that result in timeout:

```
curl -v -HHost:httpbin.example.com --resolve "httpbin.example.com:$SECURE_INGRESS_PORT:$INGRESS_HOST" --cacert example.com.crt "https://httpbin.example.com:$SECURE_INGRESS_PORT/status/418"
```

Comment: Could you try to follow these [docs](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/)? I think there they are newer and there is difference with how you create the secret and how you use it in ingress gateway yaml. Additionally could you check [readiness port](https://istio.io/news/releases/1.6.x/announcing-1.6/upgrade-notes/#change-the-readiness-port-of-gateways) of your istio gateway if you upgrade to 1.6?

Comment: What is your infrastructure? Do you have the `environment variables INGRESS_HOST and SECURE_INGRESS_PORT ` set and you can print them? You could start with changing hosts in gateway from `httpbin.example.com` to `*`. Take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/5686).